# Change displayed image in listbox at runtime

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have a Listbox bound to an Observable collecton that has a different image displayed depending on the data within it like so:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PersonTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="id" Text="{Binding Id}" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

I then use it later:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ListBox x:Name="personListBox" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PersonTemplate}" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding PersonCollection}"/>
</Grid>
```

However this means I have created the ImagePath property as part of the Person which isn't really correct, as it is part of the ViewModel rather than the model. Is it possible to somehow to add a binding into the ViewModel that I can pass the Id into an change the image accordingly?

EDIT:
I actually after some playing found a way to do it but I am not sure if it is a sensible approach. I created a ValueConverter and used it to change the value.

```
public class IdToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int id = (int)value;
        string img;

        switch (id)
        {
            case 1: img = @"Resources/Image/image1.png"; break;
            case 2: img = @"Resources/Image/image2.png"; break;
            default: img = @"Resources/Image/unknown.png"; break;
        }

        return img;
    }
```

Then this works:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <local:IdToImageConverter x:Key="IdImageConverter"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PersonTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="{Binding Id,Converter={StaticResource IdImageConverter}}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="id" Text="{Binding Id}" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Comment: This question would be improved if it contained a small description of the purpose the UI, especially what the image represents.  The answer to this question depends quite critically on this info since it could effect the solution quite dramatically.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have had to edit what I am trying to achieve because it is to do with what I am doing at work. But basically the idea is that it's a list of items that displays in the WP7 page and each item has a type. So for example 100 in the list, each could be one of four types and then a corresponding image for that type needs to be displayed in the list box

Comment: I kinda guess that was what you were doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common requirement and the most common solution it code a specific `IValueConverter` as your edit shows.  However since its a common requirement it would be better to create a common chunk of code that could be used to handle this.

See this [blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/06/09/yet-another-blog-about-ivalueconverter.aspx) for an example of a common converter implementation (its called `StringToObjectConverter` but don't let that put you off).

You could then add a converter to the view:-

```
         <local:StringToObjectConverter x:Key="TypeToImageSource">
             <ResourceDictionary>
                 <BitmapImage UriSource="Resources/Image/image1.png" x:Key="1" />
                 <BitmapImage UriSource="Resources/Image/image2.png" x:Key="2" />
                 <BitmapImage UriSource="Resources/Image/unknown.png" x:Key="__default__" /> 
            </ResourceDictionary>
         </local:StringToObjectConverter>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks interesting and I will investigate further. I wasn't sure using the ValueConverters in this way was how you were supposed to do it but I'm glad to see I wasn't far off

Comment: I've had a look at the code from the blog but unfortunately it seems to fail saying `FirstOrDefault` doesn't exist. I'm guessing this might be something to do with it being WP7. Do you possibly have an example of this class that is WP7 compatible?

Comment: @Firedragon:  "supposed" thats very dangerous.  Perhaps you should take a step back and ask what are __my__ objectives when using MVVM and is my approach acheiving them.  If the answer is yes then who is there to tell you you're  _supposed_ to do it differently.  Personally I think it is the views job to worry about images that represent stuff and its the models job present a value that is be displayed using whatever stuff the view sees fit.  Seems like this acheives that seperation without writing view specific code (although I'm not sure thats always a bad thing either).

Comment: @Firedragon:  Include the `using System.Linq`

Comment: Thanks for that input, very helpful. I am trying to be as pure in my approach as I can but sometimes tying yourself in knots just to get it to fit is a bad idea and something I tend to be a little guilty of

Comment: I think I am having some issues because in the `ResourceDictionary` I am trying to use `Image` and seeing no images displayed I guess I am Binding the Image in my list to an image and it doesn't like it very much. The `BitmapImage` doesn't seem to like having a Source and changing it to UriSource didn't help.

Comment: @Firedragon:  Sorry you are right it should be `UriSource`.  I'll edit to correct.

Comment: Once I realised my key to the Dictionary was the wrong case it all started working. Doh! Many thanks, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. Are you saying that `ImagePath` is not a property of the `PersonCollection` collection, that it belongs to some other collection? If so, you can reference it by specifying the `DataContext` as follows:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PersonTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image DataContext="{Binding ImageCollection}" 
                   Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="id" Text="{Binding Id}" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

**EDIT:**
Re-reading your question I think you're asking how to bind an image that is selected depending on the `Id` property of `PersonCollection`. To do that, create a collection called `ImageCollection` in your ViewModel, containing the property `ImagePath`, which contains a list of images that are created corresponding to the list of `Id`s appearing in `PersonCollection` and bind it as shown above.

Comment: So what you are saying here is that having two collections, one for the images, one for the people. If I keep the two collections in sync then the correct ones will be picked? I was hoping there would be a way of calling a function in the ViewModel that returns an image depending on the Id but if this isn' possible your solution seems sensible. Thanks